# Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: api, authentication, httprequest, bug, proxy

I am making a callout from my PartnerBusinessOrg to one of it's underlying Orgs.
Each Org has a connected app, originating from a templating org within them.

When I am trying to make a callout to the underlying Org to retrieve a RefreshToken I recieve the following message in my debug log:

"Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error" "

The request has worked before, however since a week I am facing this issue. When I execute the same request from Postman it does work. The endpoint is added as a remote site setting

The code responsible for the retrieval of the RefreshToken gets executed from a trigger that executes a class that implements Queueable:

```
private class ThirdJob implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {
        private SignUpRequest signUpRequest;

        public ThirdJob(SignUpRequest signUpRequest) {
            this.signUpRequest = signUpRequest;
        }

        public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
            queueGetRefreshToken();
        }

        private void queueGetRefreshToken() {
            OrganizationAuthorizationController.getRefreshToken(signUpRequest.AuthCode, signUpRequest.FullOrgId__c, signUpRequest.Id, signUpRequest.Company);
        }
    }
```

Here is the getRefreshToken method:

```
public static void getRefreshToken(String authCode, String organizationId, String signUpRequestId, String company){
        try { 
            String orgBaseUrl = mimicBaseUrl(company);
            HttpRequest req = createAuthHttpRequest(orgBaseUrl, authCode, 'authorization_code');
    
            Http http = new Http();
            HttpResponse response = http.send(req); // CODE BREAKS HERE
    
            String refreshToken = extractTokenFromResponse(response, 'refresh_token');
    
            Mysolution_Organization_Authorization__c orgAuth = new Mysolution_Organization_Authorization__c();
            orgAuth.Company__c = company;
            orgAuth.Organization__c = organizationId;
            orgAuth.SignUpRequest__c = signUpRequestId;
            orgAuth.RefreshToken__c = refreshToken;
            insert orgAuth;
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug(e.getMessage());
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Auth method looks like this:

```
 @TestVisible
    private static HttpRequest createAuthHttpRequest(String orgBaseUrl, String codeOrToken, String grantType){
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(orgBaseUrl + '/services/oauth2/token');
        req.setMethod('POST');

        String clientCredentialParams = '&client_id=' + MetadataConfig.CONNECTED_APP_CLIENT_ID + '&client_secret=' + MetadataConfig.CONNECTED_APP_CLIENT_SECRET;
        String reqBody; 

        if (grantType == 'authorization_code'){
            reqBody = 
            'grant_type=authorization_code&code=' + codeOrToken + 
            + clientCredentialParams +
            + '&redirect_uri=' + MetadataConfig.CONNECTED_APP_CALLBACK_URL;
        }

        if (grantType == 'refresh_token'){
            reqBody = 
            'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(codeOrToken, 'UTF-8') + 
            + clientCredentialParams;
        } 

        req.setBody(reqBody);
        return req;
    }
```

I also tried to call them from the trigger directly (using the @future(callout=true) decorator) which resulted in the exact same problem